# How to deploy/versioning database with Cruise Control Net?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Hi i have configured the basics of cruise control to make releases, and automated nunit test using just MSBuild. Now i'm wondering if is possible to deploy/versioning databases with this?

I'm a beginner at CCNet .So if is possible some suggestions or tutorials (if there are) . Also if someone knows a free tool for database deployment/versioning let me know.. i will be grateful.

Thanks in advance
Hugh

Answer (score 0):

It isn't free but [SQL Source Control from RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content/SQL_Source_Control/help/3.0/SSC_deploying) can do what you're looking for, assuming it's a SQL Server database. It has a commandline interface that you can use in CCNet tasks. The easy approach of just migrating up is... easy, the changes are applied to your database schema / data. There was an issue with v2x of the tool that they've overcome with 3, which is that if you were to rename a table column then it would delete the column and create a new one with the right name. Obviously that's quite a big problem if you've got data you want to keep, so with v3 there's the concept of migrations and this allows you to specify alter scripts so instead of dropping the column you could script the change non-destructively.

As far as I know, at this time, they don't have anything that allows you to roll back your version.

Otherwise you could take a look at [database migration tools](http://benscheirman.com/2008/06/net-database-migration-tool-roundup), there seemed to be some promise for these in .Net at least. There is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437346/net-database-migration-tool) that has some other tools (again for .net) and then there's this [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database+migration+tool](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=database%20migration%20tool) which is not restricted to any language but is general database migrations

Comment: thanks a little bit late the answer .. but i will check your recomendation ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for ways to version and migrate databases, one such tool is [dbdeploy.net](https://github.com/brunomlopes/dbdeploy.net) . I've hosted it on github after forking it and doing some work. Latest version is fully up to date and has some interesting features (done by someone who also uses it and sent a pull request).